# How does __attribute__((packed)) for a field affect a struct which contains this field?

Tags: c, gcc

Why is my entire structure packed if I have a packed field in it?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
struct foo {
  int a;
} __attribute__((packed));
 
struct bar {
  char b;
  struct foo bla;
  char a;
};
 
int main() {
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(struct bar));
  return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/bjoZHB

Sizeof of `bar` struct is 6, but it should be 12, because it should be aligned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems because `__attribute__((packed))` means use the minimum memory for structure, it also means that it can ignore alignment for siding members when it is in another structure. Check following structure:

```
struct bar {
  char b;
  __attribute__((packed)) int bla;
  char a;
};
```

When you check size for this structure, it will be 6. This happens because it ignores member alignment for 2 side members(`a` and `b` here). But this structure:

```
struct bar {
  char b;
  __attribute__((packed)) int bla;
  char a;
  int c;
};
```

has size of 12, because it is aligned `c` on 4 bytes boundary. In your case, if you use `aligned` attribute too at same time, it works as you expect:

```
struct bar {
  char b;
  __attribute__((aligned (4), packed)) int bla;
  char a;
};
```

This structure size is 12.

**Update:**

I only found this in `GCC`'s *aligned* section of [attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html). I think it is related to what I mentioned here:

> The **aligned** attribute can only increase the alignment; but you can
>   decrease it by specifying **packed** as well

.Just remember that if you want to keep child structure packed but main structure aligned, you need to use 2 attributes in 2 different declarations. For example following structure has size of 12:

```
struct foo {
  char b;
  int a;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct bar {
  char b;
  __attribute__((aligned(4))) struct foo bla;
  char a;
};
```

but if you use `aligned()` in declaration of `foo` as `__attribute__((aligned (4), packed))`, size will be 16. This happens because `foo` gets aligned too, and it will not be useful in case of packing.

Comment: Where can I read about "means that it can ignore alignment when it is in another structure" I didn't find it in the gcc docs or anywhere. :(

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay it had a "it seems" at start of sentence too. but I found 1 sentence about it in gcc manual and I add it to reply.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the same cite, then it seems it is an ISO C requirement. :) UPDATE: Sorry, wrong cite, I saw this:  "ISO C standard to be at least a perfect multiple of the lowest common multiple of the alignments of all of the members of the struct"